# Excel: Sum numbers inside a text block in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Lets say there is some text in a cell that reads

"this is a block of text (.7) and in this block of text (1.2) there are numbers (2.5) and these numbers need to be added together (.4)"

The answer to the sum of all these numbers would be .7+1.2+2.5+.4= 4.8

My question is, is there a way that I can have excel add all the numbers together from a block of text and just output the answer? It will always be the sum of the numbers and the numbers will always be positive. The amount of numbers will vary, it could be 2 it could be 15, could be anything.

What I have tried so far: I've tried "=sum" and highlighting the entire cell which always gives the answer "0"

Comment: There is - will likely need VBA. What have you tried?

Comment: i've just tried simple formulas thus far and as expected it is not working in the slightest.

Comment: What formulas...please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post.  Is it always going to be four numbers? Is it always addition?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Addum(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, L As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String
    s = rng.Value
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    arr = Split(temp, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        Addum = Addum + CDbl(a)
    Next a
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

The original code tries to convert a standalone period into a number.  Replace the original UDF with this version:

```
Public Function Addum(rng As Range) As Double
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
'       VERSION #2
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim s As String, L As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String
    s = rng.Value
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    arr = Split(temp, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If IsNumeric(a) Then
            Addum = Addum + CDbl(a)
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

This version *(VERSION 3)* will only process numbers encapsulated in parens:

```
Public Function Addum(rng As Range) As Double
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
'       VERSION #3
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim s As String, L As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String
    s = rng.Value
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Or CH = "(" Or CH = ")" Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    arr = Split(temp, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If Left(a, 1) = "(" Then
            a = Mid(a, 2, Len(a) - 2)
            If IsNumeric(a) Then
                Addum = Addum + CDbl(a)
            End If
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

Comment: thank you! what you have given works perfectly for what I asked, however when I ask it to find the sum of something like:  

"there is a number (.3); and another number (.2); and another number (.2); and another (.4); then this one (.3); and this one (.4); and lastly this one (.2)."  

I end up getting #VALUE! Is there any way that this can be fixed?

Comment: Seems as though the use of ";" after the parentheses doesn't effect the outcome but for some reason the "." at the end does,

Comment: @billmartin  ***I VERIFY THE PROBLEM*** ......................I will investigate and update later!

Comment: @billmartin  I found the problem........................see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks again, I'm not sure if I should keep asking you here or if I should be making another post all together. But is there a way to get the function to ignore numbers that are not in parentheses? If I have a date in the text block lets say 5/2 it will count both the 5 and the two in the calculation and the answer would be 7 off. I apologize for my rudimentary knowledge level when it comes to vba.

Comment: @billmartin  **It is possible**

Comment: @billmartin See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: is there any way this can be edited so that it will ignore words in parenthesis? This seems to be working well other than when there are words in parenthesis for example "this is a test (.5) and im trying to see ( if this will work) hopefully it will (1.2)" the answer here should be 1.7 but it ruturns a #VALUE!.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a UDF using Regular Expressions which will add only those values that are within parentheses:

```
Option Explicit
Function sumNumsInParenth(S As String) As Double
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim dSum As Double

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\((\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\)"
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        For Each M In MC
            dSum = dSum + M.submatches(0)
        Next M
    End If
End With

sumNumsInParenth = dSum

End Function
```

**Explanation of the Regex pattern**

***capture floating point numbers within parentheses, integer portion optional***

```
\((\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the opening parenthesis character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\(`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the regular expression below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\.\d+)?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
    - [Match the character “.” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
    - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the closing parenthesis character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\)`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This array formula will do it:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",99)),")",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:100)-1)*99+1,99))),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",99)),")",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:100)-1)*99+1,99))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]