# Edit VBA UDF to sum numbers in parenthesis while ignoring words in parenthesis

Tags: excel, vba, macos, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that will look in a given cell for numbers inside of parenthesis then sum all numbers inside of parenthesis in a given cell, it works well 90% of the time but when I have something inside of parenthesis that is not a number i.e a word or phrase, it will return #VALUE! I'm trying to fix this so that it will ignore words etc that are inside parenthesis. Also for some reason, having a "." after parenthesis makes it so that the numbers in the parenthesis before the "." are ignored when they shouldn't be.

#### screenshot of problems explained above

[image: screenshot of problems explained above]

The function is as follows

```
Public Function Addum(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, L As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String
    s = rng.Value
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Or CH = "(" Or CH = ")" Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    arr = Split(temp, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If Left(a, 1) = "(" Then
            a = Mid(a, 2, Len(a) - 2)
            If IsNumeric(a) Then
                Addum = Addum + CDbl(a)
            End If
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

this question is different from [Excel: Sum numbers inside a text block in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280451/excel-sum-numbers-inside-a-text-block-in-a-cell)
because im asking for it to work when there are words inside of parenthesis present and when there are "." after the parenthesis.

thanks in advance for any help that you can provide!

Comment: @ScottCraner - that question is the source of the posted code

Comment: @TimWilliams and either of the other two answers will already ignore the text.

Comment: one of the answeres used regular expressions which im having troubles working on a mac and the other is an array formula which isnt working in this setting either

Comment: @ScottCraner - granted.  It seemed the OP was trying to figure out how to fix the code they had...

Comment: I reopened but it should be asked, what have you tried to adjust the code on your own?

Comment: @HaydenShirts  I posted an update.............the problem is that a string like **"(text values)"** was being reduced to **"()"** which the code could not handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function Addum(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, temp As String, i As Long
    Dim CH As String, inParens As Boolean, q As String
    s = rng.Value
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH = "(" Then
            inParens = True
            q = ""
        ElseIf CH = ")" Then
            inParens = False
            temp = temp & " " & q
        Else
            If inParens Then q = q & _
               IIf(CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = ".", CH, " ")
        End If
    Next i

    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    arr = Split(temp, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If IsNumeric(a) Then Addum = Addum + CDbl(a)
    Next a
End Function
```

Comment: This is MUCH better than my approach..........I never considered testing if in-between the parens

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a way to get it to ignore dates i.e (9 /4) would end up adding on 13 to the final answer and (9/4/16) would add 29 to the final answer.  – Hayden Shirts

Comment: Yes there likely is - why not give it a shot?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a late-bound [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) udf.

```
Function sumNums(str As String) As Double
    Dim n As Long
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    sumNums = 0

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\)"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'sum the matches
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                sumNums = sumNums + Abs(CDbl(cmat.Item(n)))
            Next n
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

For an [excel-vba-mac](/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac) that has trouble with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) this is the simplest I could come up with.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Addum(str As String) As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As Variant

    tmp = Split(str, Chr(40))

    For i = LBound(tmp) + 1 To UBound(tmp)
        If IsNumeric(Split(tmp(i), Chr(41))(0)) Then _
            Addum = Application.Sum(Addum, Split(tmp(i), Chr(41))(0))
    Next i

End Function
```

[image]